# How to show Image Full Screen that showing in iCarousel in iOS?

Tags: ios, imageview, icarousel

I am using `iCarousel` custom control to show image from web that consumed with JSON data.

Here is my codes to show image in `iCarousel`

to Load JSON Data in ViewDidLoad

```
JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc]init];

        self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [self.items removeAllObjects];

        self.items = (NSMutableArray *) [jsonLoader loadJSONDataFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.myWebsite.com/posts?category=blog&page=1"]];



- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(AsyncImageView *)view
{
    MMSPLoader *mmObject = [self.items objectAtIndex:index];

    view = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250.0f, 250.0f)];
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.3f;

    view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];

    view.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[mmObject featureImageUrl]];

    return view;
}
```

[image]

That can show image correctly. My case is when i tap on that image , i want to show that image in FULL SCREEN. So i used `GGFullScreenImageViewController`.

However when i tap on that Image to show FULL SCREEN , i retrieved Image URL and show in `GGFullScreenImageViewController`. It's fine but , i don't want to retrieve from that URL because it downloading image from web again and slowing to show.

In my idea , i saved that image when tap on image in iCarousel and show it in `GGFullScreenImageViewController`.

So i don't need to download image again.

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.i.longrunningfunctionMain", NULL);
    dispatch_async(myqueue, ^{

        UIApplication *apps = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        apps.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        MMLoader *mmObject = [self.items objectAtIndex:index];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mmObject.featureImageUrl]];
        UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

        GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
        vc.liftedImageView = imageView;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            apps.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    });

    NSLog(@"%i",index);
}
```

So should i save to local file or is there any others nice idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should use a library to save the image when you initially download it. `AsyncImageView` isn't necessarily the best choice as it just caches in memory.

That said, at the moment you can just get the image from the view. This isn't ideal, and you should save it to disk - just sooner rather than later. Look at, perhaps, `SDWebImage` for that.

To get the image from the view (typed in browser so verify syntax and API usage...):

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    AsyncImageView *view = (AsyncImageView *)[carousel itemViewAtIndex:index];
    UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:view.image];

    GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
    vc.liftedImageView = imageView;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: That first line of codes showing warning . "Local declaration of 'carousel' hides instance variable"

Comment: So you shouldn't name instance variables and parameters the same thing... Change the name of the parameter. Or, preferably, use @property with auto-synthesis and then the instance variable will be named `_carousel`...

Comment: AsyncImageView caches the image once downloaded, so loading the image again from the same URL shouldn't have any performance issues. If it is downloading again, it's either a bug in AsyncImageView, or you need to increase the cache size. The problem with the solution Wain suggests is that if you tap the image before it's finished loading, you'll get a blank fullscreen image.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with the point about disk caching - SDWebImage would be a good choice in this case I think.